# Entropy of sum of two (potentially) dependent R.Vs

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I searched all over the internet and couldn't find any general upper bound to $H(X+Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables that are not necessarily independent. Is there any such upper bound? What are the alternatives?

Comment: I searched for ~5 sec and found https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d735/c5d6e884a57ea19a4362a3eee1d06fc615b5.pdf . Does that adequately address your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $ H(Z)=H(X)+H(Z \mid X) - H(X\mid Z)$ with $Z=X+Y$ we get:

$$\begin{align}
H(X+Y)&=H(X)+H(Y\mid X)- H(X \mid X+Y)\\
&=H(Y)+H(X\mid Y)- H(Y \mid X+Y)\\
&=H(X,Y)- H(X \mid X+Y)\\
\end{align}$$

Now, $H(X,Y) \le H(X)+H(Y)$ (equality iff $X,Y$ are independent) and $H(X \mid X+Y)\ge 0$  (equality iff knowing the sum lets me know the summands; i.e, iff $x_1+y_1 \ne x_2+y_2$ for any set of values with positive probability).

Then $$H(X+Y)\le H(X)+H(Y)$$ 
is a valid general bound. If the variables are dependent and we are given $H(X,Y)$ , then

$$H(X+Y)\le H(X,Y)$$ 
would be a tighter bound.

Comment: Does it hold in the infinite discrete case (i.e., discrete X,Y with infinite support)?

Comment: I'd say yes, why not?

Comment: It should work if the entropies exist. But, does not seem to be immediate because it involves series representing the entropies of conditional variables, etc'.